# Algorithm for Table / Seat assignment

Tags: c#, asp.net, algorithm

I am currently developing a Booking system, and are in need of an algorithm to assign Company participants to Seats, based on some conditions and predefined values.

The conditions are:

- From each distinct company, at least two participants must be placed at the same table. (Given that the company has 2 at least participants)
- Companies have competitors defined. A Company cannot be seated at the same table as a competitor.

The predefined values are:

- Tables and seats are predefined.
- Companies participants and Competitors relations are predefined.

Definition of entities:

**Table:**
ID (Int, PK),
Description (String),
Number (Int),

**TableSeat:**
ID (Int, PK),
Number (Int),
TableID (FK),
CustomerID (Nullable Int, FK)

**Company:**
ID (PK)
Name (String)
DefaultNumberOfParticipants (Int)
CompetitorID (FK)

**Competior:**
ID (PK)
CompanyID (FK)
CompanyID2 (FK)

So, if i, for example, have the following preset defined:

Tables:

- Table 1 has 6 Seats
- Table 2 has 4 Seats
- Table 3 has 6 Seats
- Table 4 has 3 Seats

Company/Participants:

- Company1 has 3 participants and no competitors
- Company2 has 2 participants and Company3 as Competitor
- Company3 has 4 participants and Company2 as Competitor

I need to auto assign the total of 9 participants, from the 3 companies on the total of 19 seats on 4 tables. According to the conditions, participants from Company2 and Company3 cannot be seated at the same table. Futhermore, when a participant is seated at a table he should be accompanied (if possible) by a fellow company participant.

Any ideas or pointers towards a suitable algorithm would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If you want to program something quickly you could try 'greedy randomized' metaheuristics (GRASP) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_randomized_adaptive_search_procedure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following variation on this algorithm: [Distributing players to tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13078397/distributing-players-to-tables/13085688#13085688)

Again the overall idea is process each seat on each table in turn, seating a random remaining and valid person at it. If there is no such person available, the algorithm terminates with no result (making it a so-called [Las Vegas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Las_Vegas_algorithm) algorithm).

Depending on how many valid solutions there are, you might have to run the algorithm a couple of 100 times before you find a solution, but this is Ok, since a single run is so quick: I estimate that, for the example you gave, you should find a result in less than a second, at least far more quickly than an exhaustive search through all possible permutations.

The condition that no 2 competitors should be allowed at the same table can easily be enforced: when selecting
the next person to seat at a table, just exclude the competitors of all people already seated at that table.

The other condition, that a person should preferably be seated with at least one colleague is more difficult to do right. It could still be implemented as a hard constraint, but I suspect that there might be a significant number of situations that won't produce any results.
Therefore, I would like to suggest to make this condition a 'soft constraint', by initially ignoring this condition entirely, but evaluating every result afterwards by awarding a penalty point for every person not seated with a colleague.

This guarantees that you still get a somewhat acceptable seating even in situations where not everybody could be seated with a colleague.

The algorithm then becomes:

```
//Place everyone at a table while avoiding seating competitors together
for each table T:
   UP = a randomly shuffled list of unseated people
   for each person X from UP
      While there still is at least one seat available at T AND
          X is not a competitor of anyone already seated at T
             seat X at T

   if T still has one or more seats available
      abort;  //With the decisions taken so far, noone can be seated at T. This run has no result.

//Complete seat configuration found. Award a penalty point for evey person not seated with a colleague.
penaltyPoints = 0
for each table T:
   for each person X seated at T
      If there is no other person at T that is from X's company
         Add a penalty point.
```

Run this algorithm several (hundred? thousand?) times and keep the result with the least number of penalty
points.

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem can be reduced to vertex coloring of a graph. Participants of competitor companies are connected in the graph. The number of colors is equal to the number of tables. There is an additional constraint that each color/table has a maximum number of nodes associated with it.

As for the aspect of the problem wherein atleast 2 people of the same company need to sit at the same table, whenever you color a new node, endure another node of the same company has the same color, else try to color another node of the same company with the same color.